# Sendkeys emulating WIN+ALT+4

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying with no success to emulate the `WIN`+`ALT`+`4` in a batch file:

```
powershell -c "$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.SendKeys('(^{ESCAPE})%{4}')
```

The command above was my last attempt.

Comment: SendKeys has no way to simulate the Windows key being pressed. You may have better luck with AutoHotKey, but I don't use it so I can't say.

Comment: Also, if you're doing something in a batch file, as oppised to directly in cmd.exe, any `%` character would need to be doubled, (one escapes the other).